# django models order index field

Tags: django, django-models

I need to add a new field to my model, to order the queries. This field should be a PositiveIntegerField and ideally with a select box to choose values, from 1 to the total of elements in the DB. It would be something like that:

```
class Poll(models.Model)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=xrange(Poll.objects.count()))
```

But of course, this is not possible in real life. The Poll model is not yet defined, so I can't execute Poll.objects.count(). Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you very much.

Update: I'm just using django-admin as input interface.

Update 2: I have decided to override ModelAdmin.get_form() to modify the formfield. Shall I define the PollForm as well?

Comment: You might want to do this at the form level rather than the models

Comment: I am just using the admin to input data, so I think dorms don't really fit my needs...

Comment: ok, following karthikr advice, I am overriding ModelAdmin.get_form(). Shall I define a PollForm, even when I'm just using the admin interface?